# restart VOLTTRON on edge device

Tags: linux, volttron

If I am running [VOLTTRON](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/main/) on an edge device that runs on a [Minimal Debian based Linux OS](https://www.armbian.com/) and building goes through a power interruption. How can VOLTTRON automatically restart as a Linux service?

Also I am running the [VOLTTRON drivers](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/main/driver-framework/drivers-overview.html) like the BACnet proxy agent, forwarding, listener agent, and platform driver; how do I get these up and running again?

Answer (score 0):

With agents you can have them auto start by "enabling them"

```
vctl enable agent
```

You can set the priority so that the bacnet proxy starts up before the platform driver.

There is https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/main/scripts/admin/volttron.service which is a systemd file to get your volttron running after the power outage.